# SignalR chat on azure

Tags: azure, signalr

I have created a small and simple chat with signalr on a azure website. That doesn't work as expected.
After some hours on Google I found out, that signalr should be implemented different on Azure.

What is best practise?
Any good examples?

It should work on both mobile and in normal browsers.

Comment: Now it is working using websocket. But that solution has limitations. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Per the docs at: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites

> **Deploying a SignalR Web App to Azure App Service**
>
> SignalR doesn't add any particular complications to deploying an
>   application to Azure versus deploying to an on-premises server. **An
>   application that uses SignalR can be hosted in Azure without any
>   changes in configuration or other settings (though for WebSockets
>   support, see [Enabling WebSockets on Azure App Service](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites#websocket) below.)...**

Comment: Thanks. I went through it and its now working. Though I get some problems if I have more than X connections to the web service. Then I have to scale up the pricing tier to standard. There is no limitations on standard tier.

Answer (score 0):

To get signalr working when deploying to azure, I had to use

> appBuilder.SetDataProtectionProvider(new MachineKeyProtectionProvider());

inside my Startup.cs Configure() method.

link to MachineKeyProtectionProvider [gist](https://gist.github.com/HNeukermans/d2252e9107ded8d0fb867aef300222f4)

This is actually a workaround to this problem but it seems to work.
Follow this link : [ASP.NET 5 app in Azure doesn't work with SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3659)

Comment: Do you know if this also needed for the ASP.NET Core SignalR?